# Given that $\int\limits_{-2}^0 f(x) \,\text{d}x=3 $, show that $\int\limits_0^2 f(x-2) \,\text{d}x =3 $.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be continous in $[-2,0]$ and $\displaystyle\int\limits_{-2}^0 f(x) \,\text{d}x=3 $. I'm supose to prove that $\displaystyle\int\limits_0^2 f(x-2) \,\text{d}x =3 $ but without $u$ substitutions. How to prove it ?

Comment: Substitute $$t=x-2$$ then we get $$dx=dt$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Ah, clever way of avoiding the problem. You used $t$ substitution instead of $u$ substitution... :-)

Comment: greetings to Sweden!

Comment: Hahaha But how do i know that i can do this substitution in $[0,2]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements) namely:

$\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$

Comment: That will be possible at $f:\mathbb{R}\to I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. But i do not know if this is valid to $f:[-2,0]\to I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The $[-2,0]$ was added after I posted my answer. Let me take a look.

Comment: It shouldn't really make a difference. Instead of $\int_{-2}^0f(x)dx=F(0)-F(-2)$ you get $\int_{0}^2f(x-2)dx=F((2)-2)-F((0)-2)$

Comment: That was my trouble, how to prove that $f(x-2)$ are integrable in $[0,2]$ ?